# How can I sort an object using a key value of the object

Tags: javascript, sorting

```
    orders: {
    orders: [
      {
        addressDetails: {
          addressLine1: 'Dhruba\'s Home',
          addressLine2: 'Dhauliguri',
          city: 'Kokrajhar',
          email: 'dhruba@mac.com',
          landmark: 'Chandrapara Gas Agency',
          phoneNo: '9876543210',
          pinCode: '783321'
        },
        products: [
          {
            id: '-MKBFRQbLhkV5yvtclpD',
            oldPrice: '186',
            productName: 'Fortune Premium Kachi Ghani Pure Mustard Oil',
            unitPrice: '128',
            units: 3
          },
          {
            id: '-MKBFdmYxUmkl0snpb-o',
            oldPrice: '220',
            productName: 'Saffola Low Cholestrol Mustard Oil (Bottle)',
            unitPrice: '140',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLtgt8Q1t7lSSLqYsH',
            oldPrice: '840',
            productName: 'Tide Extra Power Jasmine & Rose Detergent Powder - Brand Offer',
            unitPrice: '729',
            units: 1
          }
        ],
        time: '26/01/2021, 10:42:17',
        userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2',
        amount: 1253,
        id: '-MRx5pf06D6Jq-dha9L5'
      },
      {
        addressDetails: {
          addressLine1: 'Dhruba\'s Home',
          addressLine2: 'Dhauliguri',
          city: 'Kokrajhar',
          email: 'dhruba@mac.com',
          landmark: 'Chandrapara Gas Agency',
          phoneNo: '9876543210',
          pinCode: '783321'
        },
        products: [
          {
            id: '-MKBFRQbLhkV5yvtclpD',
            oldPrice: '186',
            productName: 'Fortune Premium Kachi Ghani Pure Mustard Oil',
            unitPrice: '128',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKBFdmYxUmkl0snpb-o',
            oldPrice: '220',
            productName: 'Saffola Low Cholestrol Mustard Oil (Bottle)',
            unitPrice: '140',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKF-drZP73W4DfO72bl',
            oldPrice: '375',
            productName: ' Aashirvaad Shudh Chakki Whole Wheat Atta',
            unitPrice: '331',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLt0meR1fvFF4ZgNY2',
            oldPrice: '417',
            productName: 'Tata Premium Tea (Pouch)',
            unitPrice: '371',
            units: 1
          }
        ],
        time: '26/01/2021, 20:19:07',
        userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2',
        amount: 970,
        id: '-MRz9rMOBbWcCY-fFDd8'
      },
      {
        addressDetails: {
          addressLine1: 'Dhruba\'s Home',
          addressLine2: 'Dhauliguri',
          city: 'Kokrajhar',
          email: 'dhruba@mac.com',
          landmark: 'Chandrapara Gas Agency',
          phoneNo: '9876543210',
          pinCode: '783321'
        },
        products: [
          {
            id: '-MKBFRQbLhkV5yvtclpD',
            oldPrice: '186',
            productName: 'Fortune Premium Kachi Ghani Pure Mustard Oil',
            unitPrice: '128',
            units: 1
          }
        ],
        time: '25/01/2021, 15:25:05',
        userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2',
        amount: 128,
        id: '-MRsxyfq3vWm1dFZl_oW'
      },
      {
        addressDetails: {
          addressLine1: 'Dhruba\'s Home',
          addressLine2: 'Dhauliguri',
          city: 'Kokrajhar',
          email: 'dhruba@mac.com',
          landmark: 'Chandrapara Gas Agency',
          phoneNo: '9876543210',
          pinCode: '783321'
        },
        products: [
          {
            id: '-MKBFRQbLhkV5yvtclpD',
            oldPrice: '186',
            productName: 'Fortune Premium Kachi Ghani Pure Mustard Oil',
            unitPrice: '128',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKBFdmYxUmkl0snpb-o',
            oldPrice: '220',
            productName: 'Saffola Low Cholestrol Mustard Oil (Bottle)',
            unitPrice: '140',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKF-drZP73W4DfO72bl',
            oldPrice: '375',
            productName: ' Aashirvaad Shudh Chakki Whole Wheat Atta',
            unitPrice: '331',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLt0meR1fvFF4ZgNY2',
            oldPrice: '417',
            productName: 'Tata Premium Tea (Pouch)',
            unitPrice: '371',
            units: 1
          }
        ],
        time: '26/01/2021, 20:19:09',
        userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2',
        amount: 970,
        id: '-MRz9ragOIxJXilPF3MB'
      },
      {
        addressDetails: {
          addressLine1: 'Dhruba\'s Home',
          addressLine2: 'Dhauliguri',
          city: 'Kokrajhar',
          email: 'dhruba@mac.com',
          landmark: 'Chandrapara Gas Agency',
          phoneNo: '9876543210',
          pinCode: '783321'
        },
        products: [
          {
            id: '-MKBFRQbLhkV5yvtclpD',
            oldPrice: '186',
            productName: 'Fortune Premium Kachi Ghani Pure Mustard Oil',
            unitPrice: '128',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKBFdmYxUmkl0snpb-o',
            oldPrice: '220',
            productName: 'Saffola Low Cholestrol Mustard Oil (Bottle)',
            unitPrice: '140',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKF-drZP73W4DfO72bl',
            oldPrice: '375',
            productName: ' Aashirvaad Shudh Chakki Whole Wheat Atta',
            unitPrice: '331',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLt0meR1fvFF4ZgNY2',
            oldPrice: '417',
            productName: 'Tata Premium Tea (Pouch)',
            unitPrice: '371',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLtgt8Q1t7lSSLqYsH',
            oldPrice: '840',
            productName: 'Tide Extra Power Jasmine & Rose Detergent Powder - Brand Offer',
            unitPrice: '729',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLuAm-emA5UzIhXpAD',
            oldPrice: '162',
            productName: 'Ghadi Detergent Powder',
            unitPrice: '147',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLwhRgudFHBbPR18lW',
            oldPrice: '800',
            productName: 'Surf Excel Matic Front Load Detergent Powder (Carton) - Free 1 kg - Brand Offer',
            unitPrice: '720',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLyeF47-VAn9Q6nJCf',
            oldPrice: '134',
            productName: 'Exo Bacterial Ginger Twist Round Touch & Shine Dishwash Bar',
            unitPrice: '113',
            units: 1
          }
        ],
        time: '24/01/2021, 12:16:30',
        userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2',
        amount: 2679,
        id: '-MRn8D25UUj5rRfAJ5EN'
      },
      {
        addressDetails: {
          addressLine1: 'Dhruba\'s Home',
          addressLine2: 'Dhauliguri',
          city: 'Kokrajhar',
          email: 'dhruba@mac.com',
          landmark: 'Chandrapara Gas Agency',
          phoneNo: '9876543210',
          pinCode: '783321'
        },
        products: [
          {
            id: '-MKBFRQbLhkV5yvtclpD',
            oldPrice: '186',
            productName: 'Fortune Premium Kachi Ghani Pure Mustard Oil',
            unitPrice: '128',
            units: 2
          },
          {
            id: '-MKBFdmYxUmkl0snpb-o',
            oldPrice: '220',
            productName: 'Saffola Low Cholestrol Mustard Oil (Bottle)',
            unitPrice: '140',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLtgt8Q1t7lSSLqYsH',
            oldPrice: '840',
            productName: 'Tide Extra Power Jasmine & Rose Detergent Powder - Brand Offer',
            unitPrice: '729',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLubjoPaBv3lUIeEb6',
            oldPrice: '1050',
            productName: 'Ariel Matic Top Load Detergent Powder - Buy 4 kg Get 2 kg Free - Brand Offer',
            unitPrice: '899',
            units: 2
          }
        ],
        time: '23/02/2021, 12:44:06',
        userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2',
        amount: 2923,
        id: '-MUCjE5dAurxRu9Ac6EB'
      },
      {
        addressDetails: {
          addressLine1: 'Dhruba\'s Home',
          addressLine2: 'Dhauliguri',
          city: 'Kokrajhar',
          email: 'dhruba@mac.com',
          landmark: 'Chandrapara Gas Agency',
          phoneNo: '9876543210',
          pinCode: '783321'
        },
        products: [
          {
            id: '8901138509231',
            oldPrice: '250',
            productName: 'Aashirvaad Atta',
            unitPrice: '200',
            units: 1
          }
        ],
        time: '25/01/2021, 15:25:37',
        userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2',
        amount: 200,
        id: '-MRsy5ZvNiIai7U-O5Rj'
      },
      {
        addressDetails: {
          addressLine1: 'Dhruba\'s Home',
          addressLine2: 'Dhauliguri',
          city: 'Kokrajhar',
          email: 'dhruba@mac.com',
          landmark: 'Chandrapara Gas Agency',
          phoneNo: '9876543210',
          pinCode: '783321'
        },
        products: [
          {
            id: '-MKLwhRgudFHBbPR18lW',
            oldPrice: '800',
            productName: 'Surf Excel Matic Front Load Detergent Powder (Carton) - Free 1 kg - Brand Offer',
            unitPrice: '720',
            units: 2
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLyeF47-VAn9Q6nJCf',
            oldPrice: '134',
            productName: 'Exo Bacterial Ginger Twist Round Touch & Shine Dishwash Bar',
            unitPrice: '113',
            units: 2
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLzSzyLKiALq4f6RTS',
            oldPrice: '155',
            productName: 'Vim Lemon Dishwash Gel (Bottle)',
            unitPrice: '143',
            units: 2
          }
        ],
        time: '24/01/2021, 11:44:40',
        userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2',
        amount: 1952,
        id: '-MRn0w2Srovbr3-0vh9j'
      },
      {
        addressDetails: {
          addressLine1: 'Dhruba\'s Home',
          addressLine2: 'Dhauliguri',
          city: 'Kokrajhar',
          email: 'dhruba@mac.com',
          landmark: 'Chandrapara Gas Agency',
          phoneNo: '9876543210',
          pinCode: '783321'
        },
        products: [
          {
            id: '-MKBFRQbLhkV5yvtclpD',
            oldPrice: '186',
            productName: 'Fortune Premium Kachi Ghani Pure Mustard Oil',
            unitPrice: '128',
            units: 2
          },
          {
            id: '-MKBFdmYxUmkl0snpb-o',
            oldPrice: '220',
            productName: 'Saffola Low Cholestrol Mustard Oil (Bottle)',
            unitPrice: '140',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLtgt8Q1t7lSSLqYsH',
            oldPrice: '840',
            productName: 'Tide Extra Power Jasmine & Rose Detergent Powder - Brand Offer',
            unitPrice: '729',
            units: 1
          }
        ],
        time: '26/01/2021, 11:09:12',
        userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2',
        amount: 1125,
        id: '-MRxC-8BgmG2InUeUwrV'
      },
      {
        addressDetails: {
          addressLine1: 'Dhruba\'s Home',
          addressLine2: 'Dhauliguri',
          city: 'Kokrajhar',
          email: 'dhruba@mac.com',
          landmark: 'Chandrapara Gas Agency',
          phoneNo: '9876543210',
          pinCode: '783321'
        },
        products: [
          {
            id: '-MKLzSzyLKiALq4f6RTS',
            oldPrice: '155',
            productName: 'Vim Lemon Dishwash Gel (Bottle)',
            unitPrice: '143',
            units: 2
          }
        ],
        time: '25/01/2021, 15:27:10',
        userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2',
        amount: 286,
        id: '-MRsyS9Ez1_wIAxqMMIF'
      },
      {
        addressDetails: {
          addressLine1: 'Dhruba\'s Home',
          addressLine2: 'Dhauliguri',
          city: 'Kokrajhar',
          email: 'dhruba@mac.com',
          landmark: 'Chandrapara Gas Agency',
          phoneNo: '9876543210',
          pinCode: '783321'
        },
        products: [
          {
            id: '-MKBFRQbLhkV5yvtclpD',
            oldPrice: '186',
            productName: 'Fortune Premium Kachi Ghani Pure Mustard Oil',
            unitPrice: '128',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKBFdmYxUmkl0snpb-o',
            oldPrice: '220',
            productName: 'Saffola Low Cholestrol Mustard Oil (Bottle)',
            unitPrice: '140',
            units: 3
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLtgt8Q1t7lSSLqYsH',
            oldPrice: '840',
            productName: 'Tide Extra Power Jasmine & Rose Detergent Powder - Brand Offer',
            unitPrice: '729',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLubjoPaBv3lUIeEb6',
            oldPrice: '1050',
            productName: 'Ariel Matic Top Load Detergent Powder - Buy 4 kg Get 2 kg Free - Brand Offer',
            unitPrice: '899',
            units: 4
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLw4cxIo5TUgrVkgmq',
            oldPrice: '420',
            productName: 'Tide Ultra 3 in 1 Clean Detergent Powder - Get 1 kg Free',
            unitPrice: '369',
            units: 4
          }
        ],
        time: '27/01/2021, 22:06:46',
        userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2',
        amount: 6349,
        id: '-MS3h5JurxnAWlLL8J4l'
      }
    ],
    loading: false,
    error: null,
    fetched: true
  }
}
```

I want to sort this object by the time at which the order was placed by a user.
I want the latest order to be at the beginning of the array and the oldest order at the last. I tried using the sort function, but it only sorted orders for a single month. If orders are placed at different month, it cannot sort the orders.

```
fetchedOrders.sort( function(a,b) {
        var timeA = new Date(a.time);
        var timeB = new Date(b.time);
        var timeA = new Date.parse(a.time);
        var timeB = new Date.parse(b.time);
        if(a.time < b.time)
            return 1;
        if(a.time > b.time)
            return -1;   
        return 0;
    });
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by it can't sort? Can you provide some sample of data that is produced by your sort function?

Comment: There is no JSON in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using date formater like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to format the date correctly
With moment js we can compare date with milliseconds as possible
And format as we want, with [`isBefore`](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/05-query/01-is-before/) and [`isAfter`](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/05-query/03-is-after/) method

```
 fetchedOrders.sort( function(a,b) {
  var timeA = moment(a.time, 'DD/MM/YYYY, HH:mm:ss');
  var timeB = moment(b.time, 'DD/MM/YYYY, HH:mm:ss');

  if(timeB.isAfter(timeA, 'minutes'))
      return 1;

  if( timeB.isBefore(timeA, 'minutes') )
      return -1;   

  return 0;
});
```

Full code

```js
var fetchedOrders = [
      {
        addressDetails: {
          addressLine1: 'Dhruba\'s Home',
          addressLine2: 'Dhauliguri',
          city: 'Kokrajhar',
          email: 'dhruba@mac.com',
          landmark: 'Chandrapara Gas Agency',
          phoneNo: '9876543210',
          pinCode: '783321'
        },
        products: [
          {
            id: '-MKBFRQbLhkV5yvtclpD',
            oldPrice: '186',
            productName: 'Fortune Premium Kachi Ghani Pure Mustard Oil',
            unitPrice: '128',
            units: 3
          },
          {
            id: '-MKBFdmYxUmkl0snpb-o',
            oldPrice: '220',
            productName: 'Saffola Low Cholestrol Mustard Oil (Bottle)',
            unitPrice: '140',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLtgt8Q1t7lSSLqYsH',
            oldPrice: '840',
            productName: 'Tide Extra Power Jasmine & Rose Detergent Powder - Brand Offer',
            unitPrice: '729',
            units: 1
          }
        ],
        time: '26/01/2021, 10:42:17',
        userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2',
        amount: 1253,
        id: '-MRx5pf06D6Jq-dha9L5'
      },
      {
        addressDetails: {
          addressLine1: 'Dhruba\'s Home',
          addressLine2: 'Dhauliguri',
          city: 'Kokrajhar',
          email: 'dhruba@mac.com',
          landmark: 'Chandrapara Gas Agency',
          phoneNo: '9876543210',
          pinCode: '783321'
        },
        products: [
          {
            id: '-MKBFRQbLhkV5yvtclpD',
            oldPrice: '186',
            productName: 'Fortune Premium Kachi Ghani Pure Mustard Oil',
            unitPrice: '128',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKBFdmYxUmkl0snpb-o',
            oldPrice: '220',
            productName: 'Saffola Low Cholestrol Mustard Oil (Bottle)',
            unitPrice: '140',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKF-drZP73W4DfO72bl',
            oldPrice: '375',
            productName: ' Aashirvaad Shudh Chakki Whole Wheat Atta',
            unitPrice: '331',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLt0meR1fvFF4ZgNY2',
            oldPrice: '417',
            productName: 'Tata Premium Tea (Pouch)',
            unitPrice: '371',
            units: 1
          }
        ],
        time: '26/01/2021, 20:19:07',
        userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2',
        amount: 970,
        id: '-MRz9rMOBbWcCY-fFDd8'
      },
      {
        addressDetails: {
          addressLine1: 'Dhruba\'s Home',
          addressLine2: 'Dhauliguri',
          city: 'Kokrajhar',
          email: 'dhruba@mac.com',
          landmark: 'Chandrapara Gas Agency',
          phoneNo: '9876543210',
          pinCode: '783321'
        },
        products: [
          {
            id: '-MKBFRQbLhkV5yvtclpD',
            oldPrice: '186',
            productName: 'Fortune Premium Kachi Ghani Pure Mustard Oil',
            unitPrice: '128',
            units: 1
          }
        ],
        time: '25/01/2021, 15:25:05',
        userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2',
        amount: 128,
        id: '-MRsxyfq3vWm1dFZl_oW'
      },
      {
        addressDetails: {
          addressLine1: 'Dhruba\'s Home',
          addressLine2: 'Dhauliguri',
          city: 'Kokrajhar',
          email: 'dhruba@mac.com',
          landmark: 'Chandrapara Gas Agency',
          phoneNo: '9876543210',
          pinCode: '783321'
        },
        products: [
          {
            id: '-MKBFRQbLhkV5yvtclpD',
            oldPrice: '186',
            productName: 'Fortune Premium Kachi Ghani Pure Mustard Oil',
            unitPrice: '128',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKBFdmYxUmkl0snpb-o',
            oldPrice: '220',
            productName: 'Saffola Low Cholestrol Mustard Oil (Bottle)',
            unitPrice: '140',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKF-drZP73W4DfO72bl',
            oldPrice: '375',
            productName: ' Aashirvaad Shudh Chakki Whole Wheat Atta',
            unitPrice: '331',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLt0meR1fvFF4ZgNY2',
            oldPrice: '417',
            productName: 'Tata Premium Tea (Pouch)',
            unitPrice: '371',
            units: 1
          }
        ],
        time: '26/01/2021, 20:19:09',
        userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2',
        amount: 970,
        id: '-MRz9ragOIxJXilPF3MB'
      },
      {
        addressDetails: {
          addressLine1: 'Dhruba\'s Home',
          addressLine2: 'Dhauliguri',
          city: 'Kokrajhar',
          email: 'dhruba@mac.com',
          landmark: 'Chandrapara Gas Agency',
          phoneNo: '9876543210',
          pinCode: '783321'
        },
        products: [
          {
            id: '-MKBFRQbLhkV5yvtclpD',
            oldPrice: '186',
            productName: 'Fortune Premium Kachi Ghani Pure Mustard Oil',
            unitPrice: '128',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKBFdmYxUmkl0snpb-o',
            oldPrice: '220',
            productName: 'Saffola Low Cholestrol Mustard Oil (Bottle)',
            unitPrice: '140',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKF-drZP73W4DfO72bl',
            oldPrice: '375',
            productName: ' Aashirvaad Shudh Chakki Whole Wheat Atta',
            unitPrice: '331',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLt0meR1fvFF4ZgNY2',
            oldPrice: '417',
            productName: 'Tata Premium Tea (Pouch)',
            unitPrice: '371',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLtgt8Q1t7lSSLqYsH',
            oldPrice: '840',
            productName: 'Tide Extra Power Jasmine & Rose Detergent Powder - Brand Offer',
            unitPrice: '729',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLuAm-emA5UzIhXpAD',
            oldPrice: '162',
            productName: 'Ghadi Detergent Powder',
            unitPrice: '147',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLwhRgudFHBbPR18lW',
            oldPrice: '800',
            productName: 'Surf Excel Matic Front Load Detergent Powder (Carton) - Free 1 kg - Brand Offer',
            unitPrice: '720',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLyeF47-VAn9Q6nJCf',
            oldPrice: '134',
            productName: 'Exo Bacterial Ginger Twist Round Touch & Shine Dishwash Bar',
            unitPrice: '113',
            units: 1
          }
        ],
        time: '24/01/2021, 12:16:30',
        userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2',
        amount: 2679,
        id: '-MRn8D25UUj5rRfAJ5EN'
      },
      {
        addressDetails: {
          addressLine1: 'Dhruba\'s Home',
          addressLine2: 'Dhauliguri',
          city: 'Kokrajhar',
          email: 'dhruba@mac.com',
          landmark: 'Chandrapara Gas Agency',
          phoneNo: '9876543210',
          pinCode: '783321'
        },
        products: [
          {
            id: '-MKBFRQbLhkV5yvtclpD',
            oldPrice: '186',
            productName: 'Fortune Premium Kachi Ghani Pure Mustard Oil',
            unitPrice: '128',
            units: 2
          },
          {
            id: '-MKBFdmYxUmkl0snpb-o',
            oldPrice: '220',
            productName: 'Saffola Low Cholestrol Mustard Oil (Bottle)',
            unitPrice: '140',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLtgt8Q1t7lSSLqYsH',
            oldPrice: '840',
            productName: 'Tide Extra Power Jasmine & Rose Detergent Powder - Brand Offer',
            unitPrice: '729',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLubjoPaBv3lUIeEb6',
            oldPrice: '1050',
            productName: 'Ariel Matic Top Load Detergent Powder - Buy 4 kg Get 2 kg Free - Brand Offer',
            unitPrice: '899',
            units: 2
          }
        ],
        time: '23/02/2021, 12:44:06',
        userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2',
        amount: 2923,
        id: '-MUCjE5dAurxRu9Ac6EB'
      },
      {
        addressDetails: {
          addressLine1: 'Dhruba\'s Home',
          addressLine2: 'Dhauliguri',
          city: 'Kokrajhar',
          email: 'dhruba@mac.com',
          landmark: 'Chandrapara Gas Agency',
          phoneNo: '9876543210',
          pinCode: '783321'
        },
        products: [
          {
            id: '8901138509231',
            oldPrice: '250',
            productName: 'Aashirvaad Atta',
            unitPrice: '200',
            units: 1
          }
        ],
        time: '25/01/2021, 15:25:37',
        userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2',
        amount: 200,
        id: '-MRsy5ZvNiIai7U-O5Rj'
      },
      {
        addressDetails: {
          addressLine1: 'Dhruba\'s Home',
          addressLine2: 'Dhauliguri',
          city: 'Kokrajhar',
          email: 'dhruba@mac.com',
          landmark: 'Chandrapara Gas Agency',
          phoneNo: '9876543210',
          pinCode: '783321'
        },
        products: [
          {
            id: '-MKLwhRgudFHBbPR18lW',
            oldPrice: '800',
            productName: 'Surf Excel Matic Front Load Detergent Powder (Carton) - Free 1 kg - Brand Offer',
            unitPrice: '720',
            units: 2
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLyeF47-VAn9Q6nJCf',
            oldPrice: '134',
            productName: 'Exo Bacterial Ginger Twist Round Touch & Shine Dishwash Bar',
            unitPrice: '113',
            units: 2
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLzSzyLKiALq4f6RTS',
            oldPrice: '155',
            productName: 'Vim Lemon Dishwash Gel (Bottle)',
            unitPrice: '143',
            units: 2
          }
        ],
        time: '24/01/2021, 11:44:40',
        userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2',
        amount: 1952,
        id: '-MRn0w2Srovbr3-0vh9j'
      },
      {
        addressDetails: {
          addressLine1: 'Dhruba\'s Home',
          addressLine2: 'Dhauliguri',
          city: 'Kokrajhar',
          email: 'dhruba@mac.com',
          landmark: 'Chandrapara Gas Agency',
          phoneNo: '9876543210',
          pinCode: '783321'
        },
        products: [
          {
            id: '-MKBFRQbLhkV5yvtclpD',
            oldPrice: '186',
            productName: 'Fortune Premium Kachi Ghani Pure Mustard Oil',
            unitPrice: '128',
            units: 2
          },
          {
            id: '-MKBFdmYxUmkl0snpb-o',
            oldPrice: '220',
            productName: 'Saffola Low Cholestrol Mustard Oil (Bottle)',
            unitPrice: '140',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLtgt8Q1t7lSSLqYsH',
            oldPrice: '840',
            productName: 'Tide Extra Power Jasmine & Rose Detergent Powder - Brand Offer',
            unitPrice: '729',
            units: 1
          }
        ],
        time: '26/01/2021, 11:09:12',
        userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2',
        amount: 1125,
        id: '-MRxC-8BgmG2InUeUwrV'
      },
      {
        addressDetails: {
          addressLine1: 'Dhruba\'s Home',
          addressLine2: 'Dhauliguri',
          city: 'Kokrajhar',
          email: 'dhruba@mac.com',
          landmark: 'Chandrapara Gas Agency',
          phoneNo: '9876543210',
          pinCode: '783321'
        },
        products: [
          {
            id: '-MKLzSzyLKiALq4f6RTS',
            oldPrice: '155',
            productName: 'Vim Lemon Dishwash Gel (Bottle)',
            unitPrice: '143',
            units: 2
          }
        ],
        time: '25/01/2021, 15:27:10',
        userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2',
        amount: 286,
        id: '-MRsyS9Ez1_wIAxqMMIF'
      },
      {
        addressDetails: {
          addressLine1: 'Dhruba\'s Home',
          addressLine2: 'Dhauliguri',
          city: 'Kokrajhar',
          email: 'dhruba@mac.com',
          landmark: 'Chandrapara Gas Agency',
          phoneNo: '9876543210',
          pinCode: '783321'
        },
        products: [
          {
            id: '-MKBFRQbLhkV5yvtclpD',
            oldPrice: '186',
            productName: 'Fortune Premium Kachi Ghani Pure Mustard Oil',
            unitPrice: '128',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKBFdmYxUmkl0snpb-o',
            oldPrice: '220',
            productName: 'Saffola Low Cholestrol Mustard Oil (Bottle)',
            unitPrice: '140',
            units: 3
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLtgt8Q1t7lSSLqYsH',
            oldPrice: '840',
            productName: 'Tide Extra Power Jasmine & Rose Detergent Powder - Brand Offer',
            unitPrice: '729',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLubjoPaBv3lUIeEb6',
            oldPrice: '1050',
            productName: 'Ariel Matic Top Load Detergent Powder - Buy 4 kg Get 2 kg Free - Brand Offer',
            unitPrice: '899',
            units: 4
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLw4cxIo5TUgrVkgmq',
            oldPrice: '420',
            productName: 'Tide Ultra 3 in 1 Clean Detergent Powder - Get 1 kg Free',
            unitPrice: '369',
            units: 4
          }
        ],
        time: '27/01/2021, 22:06:46',
        userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2',
        amount: 6349,
        id: '-MS3h5JurxnAWlLL8J4l'
      }
    ]
fetchedOrders.sort( function(a,b) {
  var timeA = moment(a.time, 'DD/MM/YYYY, HH:mm:ss');
  var timeB = moment(b.time, 'DD/MM/YYYY, HH:mm:ss');

  if(timeB.isAfter(timeA, 'minutes'))
      return 1;

  if( timeB.isBefore(timeA, 'minutes') )
      return -1;   

  return 0;
});

console.log(fetchedOrders)
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating Date() objects in your sorting function but you do not use them for comparison. Instead you are comparing the raw time strings from your object.

The raw timestamp is not sort-friendly.

If you really want to use it for sorting it should look like `2021/02/23, 12:44:06` instead of `23/02/2021, 12:44:06`

Comment: There is no JSON involved.

Comment: a) The notation of his data object could be JSON format b) It does not matter at all for what I wrote in my answer

Comment: c) at the time I answered the question it did explicitly contained the question how to sort by attribute key in a JSON objects (seems stupid to me that the question can be edited afterwards and make already given answers look wrong)

Comment: It could also be XML formatted. It doesn't matter. It makes no sense to talk about JSON or XML or CSV if there is only JavaScript.

Comment: Are you familiar with JSON? What is "{}" in JSON context to you? And what is "[]" in JSON context to you? Is it just text or is it a JSON object and a JSON array?

Comment: By the way ... JavaScript is, in your interpretation, also "just text" ;-)

Comment: The point is that many people can't distinguish JSON and JavaScript and think it's the same. Questions and answers like this make it even worse. There is no JSON involved. OP probably doesn't even know that there is no JSON involved. The code in the question isn't valid JSON. The data could come from anywhere and the source of the data doesn't change anything about the question. It's absolutely irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, I agree, its irrelevant (see remark "b" in my first comment). Since the OP used the word JSON in his question its legit for me to assume that his data object was meant to be written in JSON format (even if its not 100% valid). And when you write "The code in the question isn't valid JSON." then I think you also make it worse because JSON is not code(!). JSON is data. Thats the difference between Javascript and JSON. One is code and the other is data. .... over and out

Comment: The code in the question is code. You can write JavaScript code that is valid JSON. But the actual code in the question is not valid JSON. You interpreted something into my comment that I didn't write. E.g. `{ "a": 1 }` is valid JavaScript and valid JSON. It depends on the context if it's code or data. In my context it's code but it's also valid JSON. So this code is valid JSON.

Comment: Damn, I wrote "over and out" and now you make me answer again ;-) :-D ... Yes, `{ "a": 1 }` ist valid JavaScript but it's not (executable) code. It is always a declaration of data in any programming language that accepts this syntax. One could argue that the assignment of an initial value is done by executable code and therefore this statement could be interpreted as code, but this seems very philosophical to me. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The time comparison cannot be considered correct. You don't even seem to use the date variables you just created. The sort function should be changed as follows.

```
fetchedOrders.sort( function(a,b) {

        var timeA = Date.parse(a.time);
        var timeB = Date.parse(b.time);

        
        if(timeA < timeB)
            return 1;
            
        if(timeA > timeB)
            return -1;   
            
        return 0;
});
```

The `Date.parse()` function creates a quantifiable representation of the date/time. This is what you should compare in the sort function.

```js
var fetchedOrders = [
      {
        addressDetails: {
          addressLine1: 'Dhruba\'s Home',
          addressLine2: 'Dhauliguri',
          city: 'Kokrajhar',
          email: 'dhruba@mac.com',
          landmark: 'Chandrapara Gas Agency',
          phoneNo: '9876543210',
          pinCode: '783321'
        },
        products: [
          {
            id: '-MKBFRQbLhkV5yvtclpD',
            oldPrice: '186',
            productName: 'Fortune Premium Kachi Ghani Pure Mustard Oil',
            unitPrice: '128',
            units: 3
          },
          {
            id: '-MKBFdmYxUmkl0snpb-o',
            oldPrice: '220',
            productName: 'Saffola Low Cholestrol Mustard Oil (Bottle)',
            unitPrice: '140',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLtgt8Q1t7lSSLqYsH',
            oldPrice: '840',
            productName: 'Tide Extra Power Jasmine & Rose Detergent Powder - Brand Offer',
            unitPrice: '729',
            units: 1
          }
        ],
        time: '26/01/2021, 10:42:17',
        userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2',
        amount: 1253,
        id: '-MRx5pf06D6Jq-dha9L5'
      },
      {
        addressDetails: {
          addressLine1: 'Dhruba\'s Home',
          addressLine2: 'Dhauliguri',
          city: 'Kokrajhar',
          email: 'dhruba@mac.com',
          landmark: 'Chandrapara Gas Agency',
          phoneNo: '9876543210',
          pinCode: '783321'
        },
        products: [
          {
            id: '-MKBFRQbLhkV5yvtclpD',
            oldPrice: '186',
            productName: 'Fortune Premium Kachi Ghani Pure Mustard Oil',
            unitPrice: '128',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKBFdmYxUmkl0snpb-o',
            oldPrice: '220',
            productName: 'Saffola Low Cholestrol Mustard Oil (Bottle)',
            unitPrice: '140',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKF-drZP73W4DfO72bl',
            oldPrice: '375',
            productName: ' Aashirvaad Shudh Chakki Whole Wheat Atta',
            unitPrice: '331',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLt0meR1fvFF4ZgNY2',
            oldPrice: '417',
            productName: 'Tata Premium Tea (Pouch)',
            unitPrice: '371',
            units: 1
          }
        ],
        time: '26/01/2021, 20:19:07',
        userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2',
        amount: 970,
        id: '-MRz9rMOBbWcCY-fFDd8'
      },
      {
        addressDetails: {
          addressLine1: 'Dhruba\'s Home',
          addressLine2: 'Dhauliguri',
          city: 'Kokrajhar',
          email: 'dhruba@mac.com',
          landmark: 'Chandrapara Gas Agency',
          phoneNo: '9876543210',
          pinCode: '783321'
        },
        products: [
          {
            id: '-MKBFRQbLhkV5yvtclpD',
            oldPrice: '186',
            productName: 'Fortune Premium Kachi Ghani Pure Mustard Oil',
            unitPrice: '128',
            units: 1
          }
        ],
        time: '25/01/2021, 15:25:05',
        userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2',
        amount: 128,
        id: '-MRsxyfq3vWm1dFZl_oW'
      },
      {
        addressDetails: {
          addressLine1: 'Dhruba\'s Home',
          addressLine2: 'Dhauliguri',
          city: 'Kokrajhar',
          email: 'dhruba@mac.com',
          landmark: 'Chandrapara Gas Agency',
          phoneNo: '9876543210',
          pinCode: '783321'
        },
        products: [
          {
            id: '-MKBFRQbLhkV5yvtclpD',
            oldPrice: '186',
            productName: 'Fortune Premium Kachi Ghani Pure Mustard Oil',
            unitPrice: '128',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKBFdmYxUmkl0snpb-o',
            oldPrice: '220',
            productName: 'Saffola Low Cholestrol Mustard Oil (Bottle)',
            unitPrice: '140',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKF-drZP73W4DfO72bl',
            oldPrice: '375',
            productName: ' Aashirvaad Shudh Chakki Whole Wheat Atta',
            unitPrice: '331',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLt0meR1fvFF4ZgNY2',
            oldPrice: '417',
            productName: 'Tata Premium Tea (Pouch)',
            unitPrice: '371',
            units: 1
          }
        ],
        time: '26/01/2021, 20:19:09',
        userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2',
        amount: 970,
        id: '-MRz9ragOIxJXilPF3MB'
      },
      {
        addressDetails: {
          addressLine1: 'Dhruba\'s Home',
          addressLine2: 'Dhauliguri',
          city: 'Kokrajhar',
          email: 'dhruba@mac.com',
          landmark: 'Chandrapara Gas Agency',
          phoneNo: '9876543210',
          pinCode: '783321'
        },
        products: [
          {
            id: '-MKBFRQbLhkV5yvtclpD',
            oldPrice: '186',
            productName: 'Fortune Premium Kachi Ghani Pure Mustard Oil',
            unitPrice: '128',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKBFdmYxUmkl0snpb-o',
            oldPrice: '220',
            productName: 'Saffola Low Cholestrol Mustard Oil (Bottle)',
            unitPrice: '140',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKF-drZP73W4DfO72bl',
            oldPrice: '375',
            productName: ' Aashirvaad Shudh Chakki Whole Wheat Atta',
            unitPrice: '331',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLt0meR1fvFF4ZgNY2',
            oldPrice: '417',
            productName: 'Tata Premium Tea (Pouch)',
            unitPrice: '371',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLtgt8Q1t7lSSLqYsH',
            oldPrice: '840',
            productName: 'Tide Extra Power Jasmine & Rose Detergent Powder - Brand Offer',
            unitPrice: '729',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLuAm-emA5UzIhXpAD',
            oldPrice: '162',
            productName: 'Ghadi Detergent Powder',
            unitPrice: '147',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLwhRgudFHBbPR18lW',
            oldPrice: '800',
            productName: 'Surf Excel Matic Front Load Detergent Powder (Carton) - Free 1 kg - Brand Offer',
            unitPrice: '720',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLyeF47-VAn9Q6nJCf',
            oldPrice: '134',
            productName: 'Exo Bacterial Ginger Twist Round Touch & Shine Dishwash Bar',
            unitPrice: '113',
            units: 1
          }
        ],
        time: '24/01/2021, 12:16:30',
        userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2',
        amount: 2679,
        id: '-MRn8D25UUj5rRfAJ5EN'
      },
      {
        addressDetails: {
          addressLine1: 'Dhruba\'s Home',
          addressLine2: 'Dhauliguri',
          city: 'Kokrajhar',
          email: 'dhruba@mac.com',
          landmark: 'Chandrapara Gas Agency',
          phoneNo: '9876543210',
          pinCode: '783321'
        },
        products: [
          {
            id: '-MKBFRQbLhkV5yvtclpD',
            oldPrice: '186',
            productName: 'Fortune Premium Kachi Ghani Pure Mustard Oil',
            unitPrice: '128',
            units: 2
          },
          {
            id: '-MKBFdmYxUmkl0snpb-o',
            oldPrice: '220',
            productName: 'Saffola Low Cholestrol Mustard Oil (Bottle)',
            unitPrice: '140',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLtgt8Q1t7lSSLqYsH',
            oldPrice: '840',
            productName: 'Tide Extra Power Jasmine & Rose Detergent Powder - Brand Offer',
            unitPrice: '729',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLubjoPaBv3lUIeEb6',
            oldPrice: '1050',
            productName: 'Ariel Matic Top Load Detergent Powder - Buy 4 kg Get 2 kg Free - Brand Offer',
            unitPrice: '899',
            units: 2
          }
        ],
        time: '23/02/2021, 12:44:06',
        userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2',
        amount: 2923,
        id: '-MUCjE5dAurxRu9Ac6EB'
      },
      {
        addressDetails: {
          addressLine1: 'Dhruba\'s Home',
          addressLine2: 'Dhauliguri',
          city: 'Kokrajhar',
          email: 'dhruba@mac.com',
          landmark: 'Chandrapara Gas Agency',
          phoneNo: '9876543210',
          pinCode: '783321'
        },
        products: [
          {
            id: '8901138509231',
            oldPrice: '250',
            productName: 'Aashirvaad Atta',
            unitPrice: '200',
            units: 1
          }
        ],
        time: '25/01/2021, 15:25:37',
        userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2',
        amount: 200,
        id: '-MRsy5ZvNiIai7U-O5Rj'
      },
      {
        addressDetails: {
          addressLine1: 'Dhruba\'s Home',
          addressLine2: 'Dhauliguri',
          city: 'Kokrajhar',
          email: 'dhruba@mac.com',
          landmark: 'Chandrapara Gas Agency',
          phoneNo: '9876543210',
          pinCode: '783321'
        },
        products: [
          {
            id: '-MKLwhRgudFHBbPR18lW',
            oldPrice: '800',
            productName: 'Surf Excel Matic Front Load Detergent Powder (Carton) - Free 1 kg - Brand Offer',
            unitPrice: '720',
            units: 2
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLyeF47-VAn9Q6nJCf',
            oldPrice: '134',
            productName: 'Exo Bacterial Ginger Twist Round Touch & Shine Dishwash Bar',
            unitPrice: '113',
            units: 2
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLzSzyLKiALq4f6RTS',
            oldPrice: '155',
            productName: 'Vim Lemon Dishwash Gel (Bottle)',
            unitPrice: '143',
            units: 2
          }
        ],
        time: '24/01/2021, 11:44:40',
        userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2',
        amount: 1952,
        id: '-MRn0w2Srovbr3-0vh9j'
      },
      {
        addressDetails: {
          addressLine1: 'Dhruba\'s Home',
          addressLine2: 'Dhauliguri',
          city: 'Kokrajhar',
          email: 'dhruba@mac.com',
          landmark: 'Chandrapara Gas Agency',
          phoneNo: '9876543210',
          pinCode: '783321'
        },
        products: [
          {
            id: '-MKBFRQbLhkV5yvtclpD',
            oldPrice: '186',
            productName: 'Fortune Premium Kachi Ghani Pure Mustard Oil',
            unitPrice: '128',
            units: 2
          },
          {
            id: '-MKBFdmYxUmkl0snpb-o',
            oldPrice: '220',
            productName: 'Saffola Low Cholestrol Mustard Oil (Bottle)',
            unitPrice: '140',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLtgt8Q1t7lSSLqYsH',
            oldPrice: '840',
            productName: 'Tide Extra Power Jasmine & Rose Detergent Powder - Brand Offer',
            unitPrice: '729',
            units: 1
          }
        ],
        time: '26/01/2021, 11:09:12',
        userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2',
        amount: 1125,
        id: '-MRxC-8BgmG2InUeUwrV'
      },
      {
        addressDetails: {
          addressLine1: 'Dhruba\'s Home',
          addressLine2: 'Dhauliguri',
          city: 'Kokrajhar',
          email: 'dhruba@mac.com',
          landmark: 'Chandrapara Gas Agency',
          phoneNo: '9876543210',
          pinCode: '783321'
        },
        products: [
          {
            id: '-MKLzSzyLKiALq4f6RTS',
            oldPrice: '155',
            productName: 'Vim Lemon Dishwash Gel (Bottle)',
            unitPrice: '143',
            units: 2
          }
        ],
        time: '25/01/2021, 15:27:10',
        userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2',
        amount: 286,
        id: '-MRsyS9Ez1_wIAxqMMIF'
      },
      {
        addressDetails: {
          addressLine1: 'Dhruba\'s Home',
          addressLine2: 'Dhauliguri',
          city: 'Kokrajhar',
          email: 'dhruba@mac.com',
          landmark: 'Chandrapara Gas Agency',
          phoneNo: '9876543210',
          pinCode: '783321'
        },
        products: [
          {
            id: '-MKBFRQbLhkV5yvtclpD',
            oldPrice: '186',
            productName: 'Fortune Premium Kachi Ghani Pure Mustard Oil',
            unitPrice: '128',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKBFdmYxUmkl0snpb-o',
            oldPrice: '220',
            productName: 'Saffola Low Cholestrol Mustard Oil (Bottle)',
            unitPrice: '140',
            units: 3
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLtgt8Q1t7lSSLqYsH',
            oldPrice: '840',
            productName: 'Tide Extra Power Jasmine & Rose Detergent Powder - Brand Offer',
            unitPrice: '729',
            units: 1
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLubjoPaBv3lUIeEb6',
            oldPrice: '1050',
            productName: 'Ariel Matic Top Load Detergent Powder - Buy 4 kg Get 2 kg Free - Brand Offer',
            unitPrice: '899',
            units: 4
          },
          {
            id: '-MKLw4cxIo5TUgrVkgmq',
            oldPrice: '420',
            productName: 'Tide Ultra 3 in 1 Clean Detergent Powder - Get 1 kg Free',
            unitPrice: '369',
            units: 4
          }
        ],
        time: '27/01/2021, 22:06:46',
        userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2',
        amount: 6349,
        id: '-MS3h5JurxnAWlLL8J4l'
      }
    ]
    
    
fetchedOrders.sort( function(a,b) {

        var timeA = Date.parse(a.time);
        var timeB = Date.parse(b.time);

        
        if(timeA < timeB)
            return 1;
            
        if(timeA > timeB)
            return -1;   
            
        return 0;
    });
    
 console.log(fetchedOrders);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your `time` value in `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` format and then lexicographically sort it using `string#localeCompare`.

```js
const orders = [{ time: '26/01/2021, 10:42:17', userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2', amount: 1253, id: '-MRx5pf06D6Jq-dha9L5' }, { time: '26/01/2021, 20:19:07', userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2', amount: 970, id: '-MRz9rMOBbWcCY-fFDd8' }, { time: '25/01/2021, 15:25:05', userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2', amount: 128, id: '-MRsxyfq3vWm1dFZl_oW' }, { time: '26/01/2021, 20:19:09', userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2', amount: 970, id: '-MRz9ragOIxJXilPF3MB' }, { time: '24/01/2021, 12:16:30', userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2', amount: 2679, id: '-MRn8D25UUj5rRfAJ5EN' }, { time: '23/02/2021, 12:44:06', userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2', amount: 2923, id: '-MUCjE5dAurxRu9Ac6EB' }, { time: '25/01/2021, 15:25:37', userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2', amount: 200, id: '-MRsy5ZvNiIai7U-O5Rj' }, { time: '24/01/2021, 11:44:40', userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2', amount: 1952, id: '-MRn0w2Srovbr3-0vh9j' }, { time: '26/01/2021, 11:09:12', userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2', amount: 1125, id: '-MRxC-8BgmG2InUeUwrV' }, { time: '25/01/2021, 15:27:10', userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2', amount: 286, id: '-MRsyS9Ez1_wIAxqMMIF' }, { time: '27/01/2021, 22:06:46', userId: 'fWXFsnaK8vcHUX4QFVHaBePWvFr2', amount: 6349, id: '-MS3h5JurxnAWlLL8J4l'} ];
orders.sort((a,b) => {
  const formatDate = (date) => date.replace(/(..)\/(..)\/(....)(.*)/, '$3/$2/$1$4');
  return formatDate(a.time).localeCompare(formatDate(b.time));
}); 
console.log(orders);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var array = [{    
    "EmployeeName": "abc",    
    "Experience": "1",    
    "Technology": "java"    
}, {    
    "EmployeeName": "cde",    
    "Experience": "9",    
    "Technology": "ASP.NET"    
}, {    
    "EmployeeName": "mba",    
    "Experience": "2",    
    "Technology": "JAVA"    
}, {    
    "EmployeeName": "ne",    
    "Experience": "7",    
    "Technology": "Sql Server"    
}, {    
    "EmployeeName": "car",    
    "Experience": "6",    
    "Technology": "C#"    
}];    
//Comparer Function    
function GetSortOrder(prop) {    
    return function(a, b) {    
        if (a[prop] > b[prop]) {    
            return 1;    
        } else if (a[prop] < b[prop]) {    
            return -1;    
        }    
        return 0;    
    }    
}    
    
array.sort(GetSortOrder("EmployeeName")); //Pass the attribute to be sorted on    
document.write("Sorted Employee Names : ");    
for (var item in array) {    
    document.write("<br>" + array[item].EmployeeName);    
}    
    
array.sort(GetSortOrder("Technology")); //Pass the attribute to be sorted on    
document.write("<br><br> Sorted Technology Names : ");    
for (var item in array) {    
    document.write("<br>" + array[item].Technology);    
}
```